# Why wont Simple Html Dom php return anything when I ask to find the <a> tag?

Tags: php, web-scraping

```
require './includes/simple_html_dom.php';
$twitter = "https://twitter.com/";
$account = "Josh65485071";
$html = file_get_html($twitter . $account);
$atag = $html->find('a');

foreach($atag as $a){
    echo $a->href;
    if($a->href === "/".$account."/following"){
        $followers = $a->find('span span');
        echo $followers->innertext;
    }
}
```

This is my code.  I am trying to get the following count from my profile, but it wont return anything.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

You will not receive any (A) tags, because Twitter builds up the page you see with JavaScript using the React framework.

I've curled with `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` and this is part of the result.

```
<noscript>
<form action="https://mobile.twitter.com/i/nojs_router?path=%2FJosh65485071" method="POST" style="background-color: #fff; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; z-index: 9999;">
  <div style="font-size: 18px; font-family: Helvetica,sans-serif; line-height: 24px; margin: 10%; width: 80%;">
    <p>We've detected that JavaScript is disabled in your browser. Would you like to proceed to legacy Twitter?</p>
    <p style="margin: 20px 0;">
      <button type="submit" style="background-color: #1da1f2; border-radius: 100px; border: none; box-shadow: none; color: #fff; cursor: pointer; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 20px; padding: 6px 16px;">Yes</button>
    </p>
  </div>
</form>
</noscript>
```

Here you can see the React root component

```
<div id="react-root" style="height:100%;display:flex;">
```

So to reach that you need to use what is capable of interpreting JavaScript like V8 engine or a headless browser. Maybe Selenium would be the best for that.

Comment: How would I go about getting this then?